# Unity texture poor quality

Tags: android, png, unity3d-2dtools

I've been playing around with Xcode and Unity for a while, and have made an app in Xcode which has a scrolling background. I want to basically re-create the app in Unity 2d, using the same set of images (if possible). I've imported all of the iPad sized images that I used in Xcode, but have noticed that the quality is a lot poorer when I build using Unity remote.

The image I'm most bothered about is the background, which is a repeating texture that scrolls across the screen. Do I have to mess around with the settings in Unity to get a better image quality? I'm using PNG. Surely the image can't be too small and therefore stretching because I'm using iPad sized images and running the app on Samsung Galaxy S6. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity Remote stream screenshots to your device, so the quality is not the final.
Maybe you can try to change the settings of UnityRemote.

See

http://docs.unity3d.com/es/current/Manual/UnityRemote4.html

More info/same question:

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/408896/android-image-quality-is-poor-compared-to-the-qual.html

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Find you image in Project tab and select it, then you should see something like this in inspector, experiment with values until you get results you are happy with.